# class is not a constructor for New Event in Safari (iOS and MacOS)

Tags: javascript, typescript, opentok, tokbox

I'm using OpenTokJS and having some issues.

For some reason it fails only in Safari on both iOS and MacOS.

```
var origSetRemoteDescription =
          window.RTCPeerConnection.prototype.setRemoteDescription;
      window.RTCPeerConnection.prototype.setRemoteDescription = function() {
        var pc = this;
        if (!this._onaddstreampoly) {
          this.addEventListener('track', this._onaddstreampoly = function(e) {
            e.streams.forEach(function(stream) {
              if (!pc._remoteStreams) {
                pc._remoteStreams = [];
              }
              if (pc._remoteStreams.indexOf(stream) >= 0) {
                return;
              }
              pc._remoteStreams.push(stream);
              var event = new Event('addstream');
              event.stream = stream;
              pc.dispatchEvent(event);
            });
          });
        }
        return origSetRemoteDescription.apply(pc, arguments);
      };
```

And the part that fails on Safari is this:

```
var event = new Event('addstream');
event.stream = stream;
pc.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This is the error:

> TypeError: _class is not a constructor (evaluating 'new
> Event('addstream')')

Isn't it supported for some reason? What's a fallback I can use?

Comment: Are you sure that `Event` is the native constructor, or could it have been overwritten by something? Try inspecting the value

Comment: If you're dealing with a very old Safari version (<6 according to MDN), you might have to use [the legacy approach to creating events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent)

Comment: @Bergi it's going to the typescript/lib - thats correct, right? and its the latest ios and safari version